# Specifyin client.crt and client.key when send http request to REST API

Tags: ruby, openssl

I have the following curl command which connect to a remote server api that require the client certificate for authenticatioon:

```
curl -s -k --cert /root/client/client.crt --key /root/client/client.key https://{SERVER_IP_HERE}:{PORT}/1.0 | jq .metadata.auth
```

This curl command works just fine

Also I tried with python using a library called requests

```
import requests

cert = ("/root/client/client.crt", "/root/client/client.key")
server = "https://{SERVER_IP_HERE}:{PORT}"

r = requests.get(server, verify=False, cert=cert)
print("result returned: " + r.text)
```

It works fine as well

However when I try to do the same with ruby using for example rest-client:

```
require 'openssl'

require 'rest-client'
keypass = ''
client_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('/root/client/client.key'), keypass)
client_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read('/root/client/client.crt'))

response = RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: :get,
  url: "{SERVER_IP_HERE}:{PORT}",
  ssl_client_cert: client_cert,
  ssl_client_key: client_key,
  verify_ssl: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
)
```

I get an error

```
usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/openssl/pkey.rb:348:in `initialize': incorrect pkey type: id-ecPublicKey (OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError)
```

I cannot get it to work either with httprb gem, etc. It doesn't matter which http gem I can use, I just want a way to make it work in ruby